# Tic-Tac-Toe on a Rubik's Cube

Tags: cipher, visual, pattern, tic-tac-toe

12 friends decide to play Tic-Tac-Toe on the surfaces of an opened Rubik's Cube which looks like this:

[image: Net of a Rubik's Cube, opened out]

---

When closed, the orientation of this Rubik's Cube is as follows:

| Surface | Colour |
| --- | --- |
| Up | White |
| Down | Yellow |
| Left | Orange |
| Right | Red |
| Front | Green |
| Back | Blue |

---

Six different sets of two friends each play on six different surfaces as shown:

| Surface | X | O |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Up | Adam | Noah |
| Down | Alan | Umar |
| Left | Charles | Thomas |
| Right | Alex | Bob |
| Front | Dan | Fred |
| Back | Kevin | Ryan |

---

Match 1:
[image: Annotated Rubik's Cube net showing Match 1 outcomes]

Winning Word = **OUTLAW**

---

Match 2:
[image: Annotated Rubik's Cube net showing Match 2 outcomes]

Winning Word = **UNCOWL**

---

Match 3:
[image: Annotated Rubik's Cube net showing Match 3 outcomes]

Winning Word = **GUFFAW**

---

Match 4:

[image: Annotated Rubik's Cube net showing Match 4 outcomes]

Winning Word = **CORRAL**

---

Match 5:

[image: Annotated Rubik's Cube net showing Match 5 outcomes]

Winning Word = **______**

---

Match 6:

[image: Annotated Rubik's Cube net showing Match 6 outcomes]

Winning Word = **______**

---

***What are the winning words of matches 5 and 6?***

Comment: Is this an entry for [the September MTC](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7388/monthly-topic-challenge-3-pencil-and-paper-games?cb=1)? It involves tic-tac-toe after all...

Comment: @Stiv I didn't know about that. I just created it for fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are literally winning words because..

> ... they are anagrams of the first letters of 'the winner in each match', 'colour of the board they played' and 'its orientation when the cube is closed'.

We can see that..

> in each cube net, there are only two winners. Considering above details, we can get the 6 letters of the winning word.

We can list down them as,

> ```
> winner|surface colour|orientation
> ```
>
> Match 1:
>
> ```
> ADAM   |WHITE  |UP    (X)
> THOMAS |ORANGE |LEFT  (O)  (OUTLAW)
> ```
>
> Match 2:
>
> ```
> NOAH   |WHITE  |UP    (O)
> CHARLES|ORANGE |LEFT  (X)  (UNCOWL)
> ```
>
> Match 3:
>
> ```
> ADAM   |WHITE  |UP    (X)
> FRED   |GREEN  |FRONT (O)  (GUFFAW)
> ```
>
> Match 4:
>
> ```
> CHARLES|ORANGE |LEFT  (X)
> ALEX   |RED    |RIGHT (X)  (CORRAL)
> ```

Now using the same logic for remaning two matches we get..

> Match 5:
>
> ```
> ALAN   |YELLOW |DOWN (X)
> RYAN   |BLUE   |BACK (O)
> ```
>
> Match 6:
>
> ```
> KEVIN  |BLUE   |BACK (X)
> UMAR   |YELLOW |DOWN (O)
> ```

from where we can identify the other two winning words as,

> [**DRABBY**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drabby)* and [**DYBBUK**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/dybbuk).

*thanks to @MOehm for finding this word.

Comment: Well done. (Chamber's [word wizard](https://chambers.co.uk/puzzles/word-wizard/) suggests [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drabby).)